# javascript get element with style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get class of img which has got style display:none.

```
 <img class="visible" src="xxxx" style="display:none"/>
    <img class="notvisible" src="xxxx"/>
<img class="notvisible" src="xxxx"/>
```

Is it possible to scan all style atribute "display" and find which one is display:none;?

Answer (score 5):

If you know there is only one `display:none` element within a given subset, you can just use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector to find the hidden one:

```
var className = $('img:hidden')[0].className;
```

Otherwise, for the general case, you can use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var className = $('img[style="display:none"]')[0].className;
```

Finally, you can just select all potential elements and [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) them down to the one you want based on any arbitrary criteria:

```
var className = $('img').filter(function () { return this.style.display == 'none' })[0].className
```

Comment: `$.fn.className` doesn't exist.  You need to do `[0].className`.

Comment: With filter, you can simply do `.filter(":hidden")`

Comment: @lightswitch05 My intention was to explicitly demonstrate filtering with a callback for the general case where there is no pseudo-selector.

Comment: thank you for quick response im sure it will help, ill try tomorow

Answer (score 1):

Try with it

```
var className = $('img:hidden')[0].className;
```

Comment: `$.fn.className` doesn't exist.  You need to do `[0].className`.